# HMT collection_singular_ids= deletion of join models is direct, no destroy callbacks are triggered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

Just ran into an issue with a has_many :through association and after/before-destroy callbacks not being triggered.

Say, I have users, groups, and an intermediate relation called membership. 
I have a form that allows users to be enrolled into groups by creating a new membership record when they check off associated checkboxes. Basically an array of group_ids.

Looks something like this:

```
Which group would you like to join? (check all that apply)
[] Group A
[] Group B
[] Group C
```

And I wish to record actions such as joining a group or leaving a group to activity log table and do some other less important thigns.

I have the following defined:

```
class Group < AR::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :users, :through => :memberships
end

class Membership < AR::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :group

  after_create :log_event_to_audit_table
  after_destroy :log_event_to_audit_table

end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, :through => :memberships

  attr_accessible :group_ids   # enables mass-assignment
end
```

When a new membership record is created the after_create is run as expected. However, the after_destroy does not get triggered!

After google-ing and read up the docs I discovered the reason why:

> "Automatic deletion of join models is
>   direct, no destroy callbacks are
>   triggered" - from Ruby Guides.

Hmmmmmm...

So the join model's (in this case Membership's) destroy callbacks are not being triggered. Well that's a downer. Any reason as to why?

So my question what is the best way to work around this issue?
Should I define my own membership_ids= method in User model that calls membership.destroy directly?

Open to any suggestions about the best practices in such a scenario.

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for asking such a thorough question and then answering it here for yourself and others. That's what StackOverflow is all about!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After carefully examining [the API docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html), it turns out `has_many` and `has_and_belongs_to_many` ("HABTM") have a few options just for this case:

- `before_add`
- `after_add`
- `before_remove`
- `after_remove`

---

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups, :through => :memberships, :after_remove => :your_custom_method
end
```

Judging by how many responses I got, this must not be a very well documented/used feature.

Just noting it here for myself and others who may stumble like I did.

Comment: This is insane... many thanks to you. I was struggling with this for a way too long time.

Comment: This seems to be the Rails way to do it. Still, I think the action triggered after removing a `group` *should* be part of the `membership` model because the removal of a `group` from the `user` is in fact a removal of a `membership`. Too bad, Rails doesn't allow that without dirty workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with the same problem recently and solved it by extending association and overriding its delete method:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships
  has_many :groups, :through => :memberships do
    def delete(*args)
      groups = args.flatten
      # destroy memberships in order to trigger their callbacks:
      proxy_association.owner.memberships.where(group_id: groups).destroy_all
      super
    end
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: Why the downvote? This is hacky but looks like an actual solution to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

adding `dependent: :destroy` to the has many relationship actually calls the `before_destroy` and `after_destroy` methods in the `Membership` class.

```rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :groups, through: :memberships, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Comment: As good as it looks, all associated :groups will be destroyed as well which is not ok if triggering destroy only for :memeberships is needed.