# How do I trigger destroy callbacks for an object which is part of a join model that automatically deletes that object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, callback, associations, destroy

Rails 2.3.8. I have 3 models, User, Source, and Subscription.

```
User  attr_accessible   :source_ids
             has_many   :subscriptions
             has_many   :sources, :through => :subscriptions

Source       has_many   :subscriptions

Subscription belongs_to :user
             belongs_to :source
```

I have an interface that allows a User to edit their Subscriptions to a Source. It collects source_ids, and creates or deletes a Subscription based on the collection. The problem I am having is, quote:

> "Automatic deletion of join models is direct, no destroy callbacks are triggered."

The Subscriptions are being deleted, not destroyed. I have a callback in the Subscription model that is not triggered:

```
before_destroy do |subscription|
  [Some irrelevant object not to be mentioned].destroy
end
```

My question is, how can I trigger this callback when a Subscription is automatically deleted due to the join model?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replying to your reply in [HMT collection_singular_ids= deletion of join models is direct, no destroy callbacks are triggered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4465607)

Change this line:

```
 has_many :users, :through => :memberships
```

To this:

```
 has_many :users, :through => :memberships, :after_remove => :your_custom_method
```

And define protected your_custom_method in User model. This way when a user removes a Subscription to some Source, this method gets called.

Good luck!

Comment: Shouldn't `your_custom_method` be defined in the same file that `after_remove` is used? Not in the "User model" like you describe?

Answer (score 2):

```
@user.subscriptions.delete
has_many   :subscriptions, :dependent => :destroy    # <- setting this on the association  will destroy the related subscriptions
has_many   :subscriptions, :dependent => :delete_all # <- setting this on the association  will delete the related subscriptions
```

From the rdoc:

**collection.delete(object, …)**
Removes one or more objects from the collection by setting their foreign keys to `NULL`. Objects will be in addition destroyed if they’re associated with `:dependent => :destroy`, and deleted if they’re associated with `:dependent => :delete_all`